# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework SELECT with multiple SUM

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How do I return multiple SUMs as JSON string with ASP.NET Core API?

Model:

```
public class PriceSum
{
   public int sum1 {get;set;}
   public int sum2 {get;set;}
   public int sum3 {get;set;}
}
```

Regular T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(field1) AS sum1, 
    SUM(field2) AS sum2, 
    SUM(field3) AS sum3 
FROM 
    Prices 
WHERE 
    ProdId = Id
```

API controller:

```
[HttpGet("pricesums/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<PriceSum> GetSums(int id)
{
    return _context.DbPriceSums
                   .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                   .Sum(p => p.field1).ToList();
}
```

My return should look like this

```
[
   { "sum1":1000, "sum2":2000, "sum3":3000 }
]
```

I'm stuck....

Comment: i found this from that thread, but how do I run this? from p in m.Items
group p by 1 into g
select new
{
    SumTotal = g.Sum(x => x.Total), 
    SumDone = g.Sum(x => x.Done) 
};

_context.DbPriceSums and then????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
[HttpGet("pricesums/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<PriceSum> GetSums(int id)
{
    return _context.DbPriceSums
                   .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                   .Select(x => new PriceSum {
                   sum1 = x.field1.Sum() ,
                   sum2 = x.field2.Sum()  ,
                   sum3 = x.field3.Sum() 
                   }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I get Error CS1929 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Sum(ParallelQuery<decimal>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<decimal>'